# `y` not found when using `ggplot2::stat`

Tags: r, ggplot2

Say I want to draw a bar plot with the data below:

```
df <- aggregate(Sepal.Length ~ Species, iris, mean)
#      Species Sepal.Length
# 1     setosa        5.006
# 2 versicolor        5.936
# 3  virginica        6.588

p <- ggplot(df, aes(Species, Sepal.Length)) + geom_col()

layer_data(p)
#   x     y PANEL group ymin  ymax xmin xmax colour   fill size linetype alpha
# 1 1 5.006     1     1    0 5.006 0.55 1.45     NA grey35  0.5        1    NA
# 2 2 5.936     1     2    0 5.936 1.55 2.45     NA grey35  0.5        1    NA
# 3 3 6.588     1     3    0 6.588 2.55 3.45     NA grey35  0.5        1    NA
```

I want to add labels to my bars at mid height, this works :

```
p + geom_text(aes(y=Sepal.Length/2, label = Species), color="white")
```

But I don't want to repeat `Sepal.Length`, so I try to use `stat` but I get an error :

```
p + geom_text(aes(y=stat(y)/2, label = Species), color="white")
```

> Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'y' not found

It is strange because some variables from `layer_data(p)` works while others won't, these work for example :

```
p + geom_text(aes(y=stat(x)/2, label = Species), color="white")
p + geom_text(aes(y=stat(group)/2, label = Species), color="white")
```

This would also work :

```
p <- ggplot(df, aes(Species, Sepal.Length, yy =Sepal.Length)) + geom_col()
p + geom_text(aes(y=stat(yy)/2, label = Species), color="white")
```

Is this a bug ? How can I work around this ?

my config (on windows):

```
R.Version()$version.string
# [1] "R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)"
.rs.rVersionString()
# [1] "3.3.1"
packageVersion("ggplot2")
# [1] ‘3.0.0’
```

Comment: *"t is strange because any other variable from layer_data(p) works"* hmm no, actually, at least for me, it only works with `x` and fail with all others (that could be used)

Comment: so my last fix fails for you ?

Comment: I meant "all others automatically created", `yy` works

Comment: I have same version for [tag:ggplot2]...

Comment: so sorry, I've been sloppy, can you test if it works for group variable for you ?

Comment: it works (giving same results as using `x`)

Comment: This does not answer the question of why `stat(y)` isn't working here, but you can use `position = position_stack(vjust = .5)` even in this unstacked example to get the text in the vertical middle.

Comment: Thanks, I keep on forgetting this

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how robust it is but it seems that `x`,`y` and `PANEL` are accessible through the `.data` pronoun.

They are named with their original name and with their original value, not the one from `layer_data`,  so if I don't want to repeat `Sepal.Length` not `Species` I can do :

```
p + geom_text(aes(
  y     = .data[[names(.data)[2]]]/2,
  label = .data[[names(.data)[1]]]),
  color = "white")
```